# running django project on client's pc hiding the source code

Tags: python, django, iis

I need to know how to run Django on the client's pc using IIS or any other method. but I need to somehow encrypt or hide the source code of the program. any help?

I've searched a lot for this but found nothing useful.

Comment: No. There is no reliable way to do this, nor any good reason for wanting to do so.

Comment: It's not possible. Rather than you serve client from your own server without any access of server

Comment: @DanielRoseman the only reason that the client wants to use it as a web application. locally with no internet connection on his local network. and I just want to find a way to protect my code.

Comment: You protect yourself by licencing.

Comment: You might use tools like https://pypi.org/project/pyarmor/ But overall, all other comments apply.